# How can I separate the input and broadcast functions in this simple chat client into different threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

This is the client class that I'm using to instantiate a test client. All it's supposed to do is connect to the server, allow users to input a simple string as a message, and receive messages from the server. The issue seems to be that the nextLine function blocks receipt of messages from the server until the user has sent a new message. I know I can use threading to get around this problem, but I'm not exactly sure how.

```
package Thread_Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Client{
    private Socket socket;
    private int port = 9000;
    private InetAddress host;
    private Scanner scanner;
    private Scanner receiver;
    private PrintWriter printWriter;
    private String message = "";

        public void runClient(){
            try {
                host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                socket = new Socket(host, port);
                scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                receiver = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
                printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            }
            catch(IOException iex){
                iex.printStackTrace();
            }

            while(!message.toLowerCase().equals("close")){
                System.out.print("Outgoing message: ");
                message = scanner.nextLine();
                printWriter.println(message);
                message = receiver.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Incoming message: " + message);

            }
    }

}
```

This is just the ClientHandler class that I used to instantiate two test clients in order to test the code in my IDE.

```
package Thread_Test;

class ClientHandlerOne{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client clientOne = new Client();
        clientOne.runClient();

    }
}

class ClientHandlerTwo{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client clientTwo = new Client();
        clientTwo.runClient();
    }

}
```

This is my Server class that does the brunt of the work. I use it to create a new thread inside of my private ConnectionHandler class, so that whenever a new user connects it stores the first string received along with the PrintWriter that sent it in a hashmap. The reason for this is that I intended for the first string sent to always be the user's name(largely just for convenience and testing purposes). It is supposed to iterate through the hashmap, sending the received message to all clients that are not the client that sent it as a way of keeping the sender from receiving a copy of their own message from the server.

```
package Thread_Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
//import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Server{
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private int portNumber = 9000;
    private Socket socket;
    private HashMap<String, PrintWriter> hashMap = new HashMap<>();



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server();
        server.output();
    }

    public Server(){
        try{
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
        }
        catch(IOException iex){
            iex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //While loop to generate new ConnectionHandler for each connected client.
    public void output(){
        try{
            while (true) {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                ConnectionHandler CH = new ConnectionHandler(socket);
                Thread connection = new Thread(CH);
                connection.start();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException iex){
            iex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //Private inner class to help handle individual client connections to server.
    private class ConnectionHandler implements Runnable {
        private Socket connectionSocket;
        private Scanner scanner;
        private String message;
        private PrintWriter pw;


        public ConnectionHandler(Socket socket) {
            this.connectionSocket = socket;
        }
        //next step is to test the hashmap and then iterate through it, getting each printwriter
        //and using it to send the message to everyone.
        public void run() {
            try{
                scanner = new Scanner(connectionSocket.getInputStream());
                pw = new PrintWriter(connectionSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                message = scanner.nextLine();
                hashMap.put(message,pw);

                //The issue is that the readLine function in the client class waits for a new input, so
                //This broadcast function is only called when I actually enter a new message in a client.
                //But how to separate the broadcast and input threads?
                while (!message.toLowerCase().equals("close")) {
                    System.out.println(message);
                    for(PrintWriter out : hashMap.values()){
                        if(out!=pw) {
                            System.out.println("Sending message.");
                            out.println(message);
                        }
                    }
                    message = scanner.nextLine();

                }
                System.out.println(hashMap.toString());
                connectionSocket.close();
            }
            catch (IOException iex) {
                iex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

I apologize if any of my code is sloppy or does not follow good practices, as I am still learning. Any input for how or where I could instantiate a new thread that would allow my Client process to receive messages as soon as another Client process sends them would be of great help.

Comment: `separate the broadcast and input threads`? Can you please explain it? Do you mean you want the input in server just send to some specific clients?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I guess what I'm saying is that the clients can only get messages from other clients after they've sent messages of their own. I'm trying to make it so that when one client sends a message, every other client connected to the server receives that message. As it stands, right now they can only get the previous message after they send a message of their own, and I'm trying to fix that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BufferReader` instead `Scanner`, a `BufferReader` can check if there are avilable buffered data without blocking:

```
class Client {
    private Socket socket;
    private int port = 9000;
    private InetAddress host;
    private BufferedReader scanner;
    private BufferedReader receiver;
    private PrintWriter printWriter;
    private String message = "";

    public void runClient() {
        try {
            host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            socket = new Socket(host, port);
            scanner = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            receiver = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        } catch (IOException iex) {
            iex.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (!message.toLowerCase().equals("close")) {
            try {
                if (scanner.ready()) {
                    System.out.print("Outgoing message: ");
                    message = scanner.readLine();
                    printWriter.println(message);
                }
                if (receiver.ready()) {
                    message = receiver.readLine();
                    System.out.println("Incoming message: " + message);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```